# Fastest way to read from a csv file and write information to a new csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm currently working with csv-files with around 100k-500k rows (rows contain text and are up to 500mb).

As I need to process text data in every line, my goal is to open each file, iterate over the rows, append two new vars to each row and write the rows into a new file (each initial csv file gets a single new output file).

My first consideration was to not read all rows into memory first and then write them to a new file subsequently but to do it all in one step:

```
import glob
import csv
from datetime import datetime

all_initial_files = glob.glob('/path/to/my/files/*.csv')

for file in all_initial_files:
    output_file = create_new_path(file)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as w:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(w, some_header)
        writer.writeheader()

    with open(output_file, 'a') as f_o:
        writer = csv.writer(f_o)
        with open(file, 'r') as f_i:
            data = csv.reader(f_i)
            for i,row in enumerate(data):
                new_var1,new_var2 = process_row(row)
                row = row.extend([new_var1,new_var2])
                writer.writerow(row)
                print(datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S:'),f'{file}: Processed row #{i}.')
```

However, I encountered that the script slows down, the more rows it processes in a file (around row ~30k, you can notice that it takes the script longer to process single rows).

My question therefore is: What's the best/fastest way in python to read a csv file, process/add information and write to a new csv file. Maybe there is a solution involving `pandas` that works faster?

Comment: Do you have conversions in your `process_row` function? I noticed the tag `pandas` have you already tried it with pandas? but probably it is oversized for such a task (depending on the complexity of your `process_row` and how it can be rewritten using efficient pandas operations.

Comment: Sure, pandas can do it.

Comment: @jottbe `process_row` is basically just a regex based search within the texts and a count how often the specific pattern occurs. I tried several approaches with `csv` module, but as I never worked with pandas before, I didn't try to implement it yet.

Comment: @Johnny Pretty sure `pandas` can do it, but I wondered whether this task could be faster when implementing `pandas` and if so, how.

Comment: @trotta  500m data not much, pandas basic is numpy, So it's not going to be slow, it's going to be automatically optimized internally. If you want better performance, you might consider use numba.

Comment: Numba sounds like a good suggestion. If you haven't tried it, it's worth doing so, because you don't even have to change your logic, just run the script with numba. If you don't do this yet, maybe it also increases performance, if you reuse your regex patterns. So compile them once and reuse them.